# Can you have an interface be dependent on a class?

Tags: c#, dependency-management, solid-principles

I'm studying SOLID principles and have a question about dependency management in relation to interfaces.

An example from the book I'm reading (*Adaptive Code via C#* by Gary McLean Hall) shows a `TradeProcessor` class that will get the trade data, process it, and store it in the database. The trade data is modeled by a class called `TradeRecord`. A `TradeParser` class will handle converting the trade data that is received into a `TradeRecord` instance(s). The `TradeProcessor` class only references an `ITradeParser` interface so that it is not dependent on the `TradeParser` implementation.

The author has the `Parse` method (in the `ITradeParser` interface) return an `IEnumerable<TradeRecord>` collection that holds the processed trade data. Doesn't that mean that `ITradeParser` is now dependent on the `TradeRecord` class?

Shouldn't the author have done something like make an `ITradeRecord` interface and have `Parse` return a collection of `ITradeRecord` instances? Or am I missing something important?

Here's the code (the implementation of `TradeRecord` is irrelevant so it is omitted):

`TradeProcessor.cs`

```
public class TradeProcessor
{
    private readonly ITradeParser tradeParser;

    public TradeProcessor(ITradeParser tradeParser)
    {
        this.tradeParser = tradeParser;
    }

    public void ProcessTrades()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> tradeData = "Simulated trade data..."
        var trades = tradeParser.Parse(tradeData);

        // Do something with the parsed data...
    }
}
```

`ITradeParser.cs`

```
public interface ITradeParser
{
    IEnumerable<TradeRecord> Parse(IEnumerable<string> tradeData);
}
```

Comment: Also note: the author advocates keeping interfaces and their implementations in a separate assembly (i.e. the Stairway pattern). If I follow that pattern, `TradeRecord` would need to be present in both assemblies or I would have to have a reference from the implementation assembly to the implementation assembly (thus creating a circular reference).

Comment: Actually implementation of TradeRecord is relevant. If that's pure data class (only contains properties without any logic), then there is not much reason to intoruce interface for it.

Comment: I think it's because TradeRecord is just a simple DTO object. Ofcourse you can create an interface for this class but would you create interfaces for every other class you create? You can treat your TradeRecord class as a contract.

Comment: @Evk The author did not provide an implementation and only makes references to a few properties.

Comment: Then I think we can safely assume author meant it as a pure data object, and so no need to create interface for it. As for your first comment - It should be stored in "interfaces" assembly in such case.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is a good question that goes into the tradeoff between purity and practicality.

Yes, by pure principal, you can say that `ITradeParser.Parse` should return a collection of `ITraceRecord` interfaces. After all, why tie yourself to a specific implementation?

However, you can take this further. Should you accept an `IEnumerable<string>`? Or should you have some sort of `ITextContainer`? `I32bitNumeric` instead of `int`? This is *reductio ad absurdum*, of course, but it shows that we always, at some point, reach a point where we're working on *something*, a concrete object (number, string, TraceRecord, whatever), not an abstraction.

This also brings up the point of why we use interfaces in the first place, which is to define contracts for logic and functionality. An `ITradeProcessor` is a contract for an unknown implementation that can be replaced or updated. A `TradeRecord` isn't a contract for implementation, it *is* the implementation. If it's a DTO object, which it seems to be, there would be no difference between the interface and the implementation, which means there's no real purpose in defining this contract - it's implied in the concrete class.

Comment: Excellently explained, this makes complete sense now. As a quick aside: when implementing the Stariway pattern, would the `TradeRecord` class live in the same assembly as the Interfaces so that the interfaces AND the implementations can reference `TradeRecord` (as mentioned by @Evk in a comment)?

Comment: Yes, I think they would both sit in the same assembly. This assembly - usually called "Common" or "Shared" or "Interfaces", contains the public, shared contracts exposed and implemented in your code. You can't consume or implement ITradeProcessor without knowing TradeRecord.

Answer (score 10):

> The author has the Parse method (in the ITradeParser interface) return an IEnumerable collection that holds the processed trade data.
>
> Doesn't that mean that ITradeParser is now dependent on the TradeRecord class?

Yes, `ITradeParser` is now tightly coupled with `TradeRecord`.  Given the more academic approach of this question, I can see where you are coming from.  But what is `TradeRecord`? A record, by definition, is generally a simple, non-intelligent piece of data (sometimes called POCO, DTO, or Model).

At some point, the potential gain of abstraction is less valuable than the complexities it causes.  This approach is pretty common in practice - Models (as I refer to them) are sealed types that flow through the layers of an application.  Layers that act upon the models are abstracted to interfaces, so that each layer may be mocked and tested separately.

For example, a client application may have a View, ViewModel, and Repository layer.  Each layer knows how to work with the concrete record type.  But the ViewModel could be wired up to work with a mocked IRepository, which builds up the concrete types with hardcoded, mocked data.  There's no benefit to an abstracted IModel at this point - it just has straight data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew I was probably over-thinking it, and that was the case.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's overthinking.  It's more of putting theory to practice and finding the places in an application tier that benefit most from abstraction.